# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource ajax jquery phonegap

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, cordova-3

I am trying to run my phonegap app on ripple emulator and calling method from webservice.asmx using ajax method in jquery, but got cors error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https:\rippleapi.herokuapp.com\xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=http%3A//www.my-domain.com/WebService.asmx/selectData. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http:\localhost:4400' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.

1. Have given cors on server side (web.config):

`<system.webServer>
          <defaultDocument>
          <files>
            <clear />
        <add value="index.aspx" />
        <add value="WebService.asmx"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
      <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
              <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
              <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
          </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>`

2. My AJAX method :

   $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
   crossDomain : true,
   url: "http://www.my-domain.com/WebService.asmx/selectData",
   data: JSON.stringify(campaignData),
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(msg)
   {
   var response=msg.d;
   var resultLoop=$.parseJSON(response);
   console.log(response)
   },
   error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
   {
   $.mobile.loading('hide');
   alert("status :"+xhr.status +"  thrownError :"+ thrownError +" ajaxOption : "+ ajaxOptions);
   }
   });

Not able to resolved this, don't know where I have done something wrong or missing something
where I have to change in code so that it communicate with server and get data.

Comment: Have you looked at the actual request/response from the server in a networking tool to see what headers are actually on the response from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

was running phonegap app on ripple emulator, changed cross domain proxy setting to disabled and it worked.

Comment: If you were able to answer your own question, please mark your own answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this methods(post,delete,etc) are allowed in sever-side code or you can use chrome plug-in Access-Control-Allow-Headers. like in php

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jsonp for the cross domain ajax resuest as:

```
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url: "http://www.my-domain.com/WebService.asmx/selectData",
data: JSON.stringify(campaignData),
contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
dataType:"jsonp",
success: function(msg)
{
var response=msg.d;
var resultLoop=$.parseJSON(response);
console.log(response)
},
error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
{
$.mobile.loading('hide');
alert("status :"+xhr.status +" thrownError :"+ thrownError +" ajaxOption : "+ ajaxOptions);
}
});
```

One more thing you have add one more parameter in web method 'callback' with string type on server side as:

```
selectData(string callback){
var JSONString = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(""); 
//JSONString is a json format
return callback+"( "+JSONString + " )";
}
```

For more details you can refer to http://www.niceonecode.com/Q-A/JAVAScript/AJAX/Cross-domain-ajax-request-to-a-json-file-using-JSONP/20154

Comment: hi ,
i don't want to use JSONP as it's working fine on android device, i want to run on ripple emulator in  chrome .